# Enum vs Constants/Class with Static Members?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a set of codes that are particular to the application (one to one mapping of the code to its name), and I've been using enums in C# to represent them. I'm not sure now if that is even necessary. The values never change, and they are always going to be associated with those labels:

```
Workflow_Status_Complete = 1
Workflow_Status_Stalled = 2
Workflow_Status_Progress = 3
Workflow_Status_Complete = 4
Workflow_Status_Fail = 5
```

Should I use an enum or a class with static members?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Static members of type int seems to be inferior to an enum to me. You lose the typesafety of an enum. And when debugging you don't see the symbolic name but just a number.

On the other hand if an entry consists of more than just a name/integervalue pair a class can be a good idea. But then the fields should be of that class and not int. Something like:

```
class MyFakeEnum
{
   public static readonly MyFakeEnum Value1=new MyFakeEnum(...);
}
```

Comment: +1; without using enums you also lose the ability to programatically *enumerate* the values via `Enum.GetValues` and `Enum.GetNames`.  This can often be useful when filling in a combo box, etc.

Comment: Adding these enumeration features to your class isn't hard based on reflection enumeration static fields.

Comment: of course it's not hard.  The point is with an enum, you don't even *have* to add them.  (It's also less safe since you'd be assuming the individual values based on naming convention, presumably)

Comment: I alos found the static members can be of your own type, and that one can have localized strings, which are very important for a lot of scenarios (e.j. filling comoboxes or lists).

Answer (score 2):

Use an enum.  Even though your codes never change, it will be difficult to know what the value represents just by inspection.  One of the many strengths of using enums.

```
enum RealEnum : uint
{
    SomeValue = 0xDEADBEEF,
}
static class FakeEnum
{
    public const uint SomeValue = 0xDEADBEEF;
}

var x = RealEnum.SomeValue;
var y = FakeEnum.SomeValue;
// what's the value?
var xstr = x.ToString(); // SomeValue
var ystr = y.ToString(); // 3735928559
```

Not even the debugger will help you much here, especially if there are many different values.

Comment: You can use an own type with id / value / description  properties instead of uint. Also you can override ToString() or even use the System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay to personalize how the type will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) as this is a better design.  With the idea you are using you'll end up with a large switch/if-else statement which can be very difficult to keep up.

Answer (score 0):

I would lean towards enums as they provide more information and they make your codes "easier to use correctly and difficult to use incorrectly". (I think the quote is from The Pragmatic Programmer.